# Turning into certain inline css into a separate sheet

Tags: html, css

```
<table border="1" style="background-color:yellow;border:1px dotted black;width:80%;border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr style="background-color:orange;color:white;">
<th style="padding:3px;">Table header</th><th style="padding:3px;">Table header</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:3px;">Table cell 1</td><td style="padding:3px;">Table cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding:3px;">Table cell 3</td><td style="padding:3px;">Table cell 4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

My question is how do i convert the inline CSS in this html example into an external style sheet?

would the css look like this?

```
tr {background-color:orange;color:white;}
table {background-color:yellow;border:1px dotted black;width:80%;border-collapse:collapse;}
td, th {padding:3px;}
```

Comment: Should work fine...be sure to reference the new external sheet in the header.

Comment: Did you try comparing the before/after?  If they were different, what was different?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`table tr:first-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-child-pseudo) instead of `tr` as only the first row has inline styles:

```
table {
background-color: yellow;
border: 1px dotted black;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 80%;
}

table th, table td { 
padding: 3px;
}

table tr:first-child {
background-color: orange;
color: white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/URBMh/2/

Comment: be carefull with the `:first-child`, cause it is not fully supported in legacy browser (read IE). You should consider changing the structure of the table by adding a `<thead>` and `<tbody>` element

Comment: [It's supported in IE7 +](http://caniuse.com/css-sel2) hopefully the OP doesn't need to support IE 6 :(